# How to update Vue data after DOM changes

Tags: vue.js

I’m using jQuery sortable plugin along with VueJS. The plugin changes the DOM, but those changes are not reflected on my components data object.

I have an array of object which is rendered as list`<li>` in HTML. The sortable plugin changes order of those list items, but the vue component array order is not changed.

Any help?

Comment: Can you include a snippet or fiddle that shows what you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

There is a special third-party Vue-component that takes care of the integration of Sortable with Vue.js: https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable

It's probably best to use this instead of trying to do it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Vue Instance by declaring component instance to a variable.

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#app',
components: {
    'my-component': { 
        template: '#my-template',
        data: function() {
            return {
                list: [],
            };
        },
        ...
    },
},
```

So that you can access the data outside the instance also. Just update the data as per the changes you listen.
Like `vm.list = []` ;)